# Trouble with addition in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator, digits

I'm making some kind of calculator and the actual code is bigger and works properly...but when it comes to + operation it prints 'only digits supported' even if i write digits. Other operations like -, *, / work good.What's the problem?

```
    while True:   
        start = input("What do you want to do? + - * /  ")
        if start == '+':
            x = float(input("digit 1  "))   
            y = float(input("digit 2  "))
            res = x + y
            if type(res) is not float:
                print('Only digits  supported')
                again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
                if again=='N' or again=='n':
                    break 
        elif type(res) is float:
            print('The result is ' + str(res))
            again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
            if again=='N' or again=='n':
                break
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code, and I did not get that message. In fact, that logically cannot happen, because adding two floats produces a float, and if converting the input to float failed, it would *raise an exception*. When I run the code, I also do not see a result. The reason for this is that the indentation of the code is incorrect. Either way, this is not reproducible and/or caused by a typo, so I am voting to close.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to something shorter that a) still produces the problem; b) is as short as possible to reproduce the problem but c) can be copied and pasted by others to see the exact behaviour that you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation in the given snippet is incorrect. Indentation matters in Python (and is how blocks of code are determined, since there are no parentheses in Python). Your `elif type(res) is float` block should be indented further to correspond to the second if statement (Right now, it corresponds to the `if start == '+'` statement. Doing this correction, the code works for me. Maybe there is something else you did not post about your code that causes it to not work for you.

Corrected code:

```
while True:
        start = input("What do you want to do? + - * /  ")
        if start == '+':
            x = float(input("digit 1  "))
            y = float(input("digit 2  "))
            res = x + y
            if type(res) is not float:
                print('Only digits  supported')
                again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
                if again=='N' or again=='n':
                    break
            elif type(res) is float:
                print('The result is ' + str(res))
                again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
                if again=='N' or again=='n':
                    break
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as I see there is a mistake in the blocks of your code in the 12 code line it must be in the next level(one more tab)

```
while True:   
    start = input("What do you want to do? + - * /  ")
    if start == '+':
        x = float(input("digit 1  "))   
        y = float(input("digit 2  "))
        res = x + y
        if type(res) is not float:
            print('Only digits  supported')
            again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
            if again=='N' or again=='n':
                break 
        elif type(res) is float:
           print('The result is ' + str(res))
           again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
           if again=='N' or again=='n':
               break
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and the only issue I encountered was that the 'elif' statement is missing an indent, otherwise it worked fine...